# Best book for introduction to Syntax, with exercises

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, resource-request

I am new to the field of linguistics and I was looking for some books in order to learn syntax.

I put my eyes on two main textbooks:

Basic English Syntax with Exercises, by Mark Newson (I was especially interested in the exercises).

Understanding Syntax, by Maggie Tallerman. (which I do not know how much relies on exercises to teach the content).

Are there better books to start with?

Comment: I would start with a descriptive grammar such as Huddleston & Pullum's _A Student's Introduction to English Grammar_. It would be an excellent place to start, and it does have exercises.

Answer (score 1):

"Best" is subjective. [Grammatical theory: From transformational grammar to constraint-based approaches. Fourth revised and extended edition](https://langsci-press.org/catalog/book/287) is updated frequently, and fairly comprehensive. This might be a good place to start.